# Create new dataframe for each factor level in column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas.excelwriter

There are 50+ different levels in a column, and each level needs to be broken into it's own dataframe and written to a file (excel or csv).

I've seen this as a possible solution:

```
df1, df2, df3, df4 = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df['column_of_interest'])]
```

but is there a way not to hard code the number of data frames?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way not to hard code the number of data frames?

Yes, there is. Use a dictionary or list. Using `dict`:

```
dfs = {i: x for i, (_, x) in enumerate(df.groupby('column_of_interest'), 1)}
```

Then access your dataframes via `dfs[1]`, `dfs[2]`, etc.

Alternatively, using `list`:

```
dfs = [x for _, x in df.groupby('column_of_interest')]
```

Then use `dfs[0]`, `dfs[1]`, etc.

If you don't need to *store* your dataframe slices, just iterate a `groupby` object and use `to_csv`. This is convenient with f-strings ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), Python 3.6+):

```
for idx, (value, x) in enumerate(df.groupby('column_of_interest'), 1):
    x.to_csv(f'slice_{value}.csv')  # include value in filename
    x.to_csv(f'slice_{idx}.csv')    # include numeric index in filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the dataframes directly

```
[df1.to_csv("coi_%s.csv"%val) for val, df1 in df.groupby(df['column_of_interest'])]
```

Or with a explicit for loop

```
for val, df1 in df.groupby(df['column_of_interest']):
    #Write the df1 to csv or excel
    df1.to_csv("coi_%s.csv"%val)
```

Comment: This worked. I needed to save the csv by the column level. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way can do that using `locals` but not recommend, personally think jpp's answer is the right way for this type of request .

```
variables = locals()
for key,value in df.groupby(df['column_of_interest']):
    variables["df{0}".format(key)]= value
```